# How to achieve grouping within grouping in sql query

Tags: sql-server

I am using following query and it displays following result[image]

**Query**

```
SELECT
  Id,
  COUNT(Id) AS Cnt,
  VehNo,
  VehName,
  ValidTo,
  IMIE,
  dr.DriD,
  DriName,
  MAX(SignalDateTime) SignalDateTime,
  MAX(DateTime) DateTime
FROM tbl_gpsData gps
LEFT JOIN tbl_Veh eq
  ON eq.ID = gps.VehID
LEFT JOIN tbl_DriMaster dr
  ON dr.DriID = gps.DriID
GROUP BY ID,
         VehNo,
         VehName,
         ValidTo,
         IMIE,
         dr.DriID,
         DriName
ORDER BY ID ASC
```

I get the following result after execution but as highlighted in image i get 4 records for same vehid EQM0000009 and some other Vehids because the driID(6 th column.'DRV0000100' and so on ) is different.

I want only one record for EQM0000009 which has maximum datetime value out of 4 records . Datetime is the last column in image. How could i do that grouping within grouping?

Comment: First off, if you have table aliases such as "gps", "eq" and "dr" use them to show clearly which columns are coming from which tables. Basically, you need to find the maximum value in tbl_DriMaster and then join back to it.

Answer (score 1):

Below query will help you

```
select Id,count(Id) as Cnt,VehNo,VehName,ValidTo,IMIE
,dr.DriD,DriName
,MAX(SignalDateTime)SignalDateTime,MAX(DateTime) [DateTime]
into #temp
from  tbl_gpsData gps left join tbl_Veh eq
on eq.ID=gps.VehID
left join tbl_DriMaster dr on dr.DriID=gps.DriID
group by ID,
VehNo,VehName,ValidTo,IMIE
,dr.DriID,DriName


SELECT * FROM #temp a INNER JOIN (SELECT Id,MAX([DateTime]) AS Dt FROM #temp
GROUP BY  Id) b ON a.Id =b.Id AND a.[DateTime] = b.Dt
```